# Unable to execute: Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell on Windows 2016

Tags: powershell

I have SharePoint 2016 November CU running on Windows 2016.
I try and execute `Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell` in an administrator PowerShell command shell and it Hangs.  I cannot break in using CNTRL+C.
Get-PSSnapin shows only one PowerShell snappin :-

```
  PS C:\February 2017 CU> Get-PSSnapin


   Name        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core
   PSVersion   : 5.1.14393.693
   Description : This Windows PowerShell snap-in contains cmdlets used to    manage components of Windows PowerShell.
```

I ran :-

```
PS C:\February 2017 CU> Get-ExecutionPolicy
   Unrestricted
```

I also ran :-

```
   PS C:\February 2017 CU> [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName   ("Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell")

   GAC    Version        Location
   ---    -------        --------
   True   v4.0.30319        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell\v4.0_16.0.0.0__71e9...


PS C:\February 2017 CU> [AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | ForEach-Object { Split-Path $_.Location -Leaf } |
>> sort
```

Shows Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.dll is loaded.

Does anyone know what my problem is ?